# Why does a Qt program look wrong when compiled as a macOS bundle but fine as an unbundled executable?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, cmake, qt5

I build a Qt5-based GUI program on macOS 10.15.7 with CMake. I normally simply build a dynamically-linked executable with `add_executable()`. It looks fine:

[image]

I experimented a bit with CMake's `BundleUtilities` module and when I finally got something runnable, it launches and runs fine, but the GUI is buggy, i.e. the buttons don't have faces and the scrollbars are kind of invisible.

[image]

The app bundle is created so that it is self-contained, and contains the `libqcocoa.dylib` platform plugin.

What could be the reason for this behaviour?

---

For reference, this code generates the `.app`

```
  set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

  set(prefix "myApp.app/Contents")
  set(INSTALL_RUNTIME_DIR "${prefix}/MacOS")
  set(INSTALL_CMAKE_DIR "${prefix}/Resources")
  set(QT_PLUGIN_DIR "${prefix}/PlugIns")

  # based on code from CMakes QtDialog/CMakeLists.txt
  macro(install_qt5_plugin _qt_plugin_name _qt_plugins_var _prefix)
      get_target_property(_qt_plugin_path "${_qt_plugin_name}" LOCATION)
      if(EXISTS "${_qt_plugin_path}")
          get_filename_component(_qt_plugin_file "${_qt_plugin_path}" NAME)
          get_filename_component(_qt_plugin_type "${_qt_plugin_path}" PATH)
          get_filename_component(_qt_plugin_type "${_qt_plugin_type}" NAME)
          set(_qt_plugin_dest "${_prefix}/PlugIns/${_qt_plugin_type}")
          install(FILES "${_qt_plugin_path}"
              DESTINATION "${_qt_plugin_dest}")
          set(${_qt_plugins_var}
              "${${_qt_plugins_var}};\$ENV{DEST_DIR}\${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${_qt_plugin_dest}/${_qt_plugin_file}")
      else()
          message(FATAL_ERROR "QT plugin ${_qt_plugin_name} not found")
      endif()
  endmacro()

  install_qt5_plugin("Qt5::QCocoaIntegrationPlugin" QT_PLUGINS ${prefix})
  file(WRITE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/qt.conf"
      "[Paths]\nPlugins = ${QT_PLUGIN_DIR}\n")
  install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/qt.conf"
      DESTINATION "${INSTALL_CMAKE_DIR}")

  # Destination paths below are relative to ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
  install(TARGETS myApp
      BUNDLE DESTINATION . COMPONENT Runtime
      RUNTIME DESTINATION ${INSTALL_RUNTIME_DIR} COMPONENT Runtime
      )

  # Note Mac specific extension .app
  set(APPS "\$ENV{DESTDIR}\${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/myApp.app")

  # Directories to look for dependencies
  set(DIRS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")

  # Path used for searching by FIND_XXX(), with appropriate suffixes added
  if(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH)
      foreach(dir ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
          list(APPEND DIRS "${dir}/bin" "${dir}/lib")
      endforeach()
  endif()

  # Append Qt's lib folder which is two levels above Qt5Widgets_DIR
  list(APPEND DIRS "${Qt5Widgets_DIR}/../..")

  include(InstallRequiredSystemLibraries)

  message(STATUS "APPS: ${APPS}")
  message(STATUS "QT_PLUGINS: ${QT_PLUGINS}")
  message(STATUS "DIRS: ${DIRS}")

  install(CODE "include(BundleUtilities)
  fixup_bundle(\"${APPS}\" \"${QT_PLUGINS}\" \"${DIRS}\")")
```

Comment: What if you change `set(QT_PLUGIN_DIR "${prefix}/PlugIns")` to `set(QT_PLUGIN_DIR "PlugIns")`?

Comment: That leads to the app not launching and errors about the missing libqcocoa plugin appearing in the system log.